# Stack multiline menu with css and html

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu, transition

I have created a vertical multiline menu in HTML and CSS. When I scroll in the menu I'd like to stack the headers (like "Region" and "status" as an example from the picture below) on top of each other. Any ideas how I should think? Can I do this with different position settings in CSS or should I do some javascript?

I'd also like to add some transition for the sub-menses. When I click on the + I'd like the buttons below to expand downwards. Any ideas about that?

Code from CSS and HTML:

```css
.mainmenu-btn {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: avenir;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: solid 2px #f2f2f2;
  width: 100%;
  height: 45px;
  background-color: white;
  transition: all ease 0.5s;
  background-position: right;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: left;
}

.mainmenu-btn:hover {
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.submenu-btn {
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  font-family: avenir;
  width: 100%;
  height: 35px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  border: none;
  border-left: solid 10px;
  transition: all ease 0.5s;
  border-radius: 0px;
  bottom: 5px;
  position: static;
  text-align: left;
}

.vertical-menu {
  border-right: solid 1px #E8E8E8;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #E8E8E8;
  background-color: white;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-2 text-left vertical-menu" style="padding-right: 1px">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12" style="padding-left: 0px">
      <button class="mainmenu-btn" onclick="showHideSection('region-area', 'region-sign')">Region<i id="region-sign" class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
      <div id="region-area">
        <button class="submenu-btn prh-btn" onclick="filterRegion('Stockholm', 'region-sign')">Stockholm</button>
        <button class="submenu-btn fh-btn" onclick="filterRegion('Mitt', 'region-sign')">Mitt</button>
        <button class="submenu-btn hh-btn" onclick="filterRegion('Sydväst', 'region-sign')">Sydväst</button>
        <button class="submenu-btn all-btn" onclick="resetData()">Alla</button>
      </div>
      <button class="mainmenu-btn" onclick="showHideSection('status-area', 'status-sign')">Status<i id="status-sign" class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
      <div id="status-area">
        <button class="submenu-btn prh-btn" onclick="filterStatus(1)">Programhandling</button>
        <button class="submenu-btn fh-btn" onclick="filterStatus(2)">Förslagshandling</button>
        <button class="submenu-btn hh-btn" onclick="filterStatus(3)">HuvudHandling</button>
        <button class="submenu-btn bh-btn" onclick="filterStatus(4)">Bygghandling</button>
        <button class="submenu-btn all-btn" onclick="resetData()">Alla</button>
      </div>
      <button class="mainmenu-btn" onclick="showHideSection('skede-area', 'skeden-sign')">Skede<i id="skede-sign" class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
      <div id="skede-area">
        <button class="submenu-btn prh-btn" onclick="filterData(1)">Markanvisning</button>
        <button class="submenu-btn fh-btn" onclick="filterData(2)">Affärsutveckling</button>
        <button class="submenu-btn hh-btn" onclick="filterData(3)">Projektutveckling</button>
        <button class="submenu-btn bh-btn" onclick="filterData(4)">Produktion</button>
        <button class="submenu-btn all-btn" onclick="resetData()">Alla</button>
      </div>
      <button class="mainmenu-btn" onclick="showHideSection('tollgates-area', 'tollgates-sign')">Tollgates<i id="tollgates-sign" class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
      <div id="tollgates-area">
        <button class="submenu-btn prh-btn" onclick="filterTollgates('TG0')">TG0</button>
        <button class="submenu-btn fh-btn" onclick="filterTollgates('TG1')">TG1</button>
        <button class="submenu-btn hh-btn" onclick="filterTollgates('TG2')">TG2</button>
        <button class="submenu-btn prh-btn" onclick="filterTollgates('TG3')">TG3</button>
        <button class="submenu-btn fh-btn" onclick="filterTollgates('TG4')">TG4</button>
        <button class="submenu-btn hh-btn" onclick="filterTollgates('TG5')">TG5</button>
        <button class="submenu-btn hh-btn" onclick="filterTollgates('TG6')">TG6</button>
        <button class="submenu-btn all-btn" onclick="resetData()">Alla</button>
      </div>
      <button class="mainmenu-btn" onclick="showHideSection('kalkyl-area', 'kalkyl-sign')">Kalkyl<i id="kalkyl-sign" class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
      <div id="kalkyl-area">
        <button class="submenu-btn prh-btn" onclick="filterKalkyl('Nyckeltalskalkyl')">Nyckeltalskalkyl</button>
        <button class="submenu-btn fh-btn" onclick="filterKalkyl('FH-kalkyl')">FH-kalkyl</button>
        <button class="submenu-btn hh-btn" onclick="filterKalkyl('HH-kalkyl')">HH-kalkyl</button>
        <button class="submenu-btn prh-btn" onclick="filterKalkyl('BH-kalkyl')">BH-kalkyl</button>
        <button class="submenu-btn all-btn" onclick="resetData()">Alla</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Sofia Malmsten, did you have time to take a look at the answer I posted?

Answer (score 0):

This can be implemented quite easily with some basic CSS and JavaScript.

### HTML structure and CSS

In order to unfold the menu blocks you can use a little CSS trick: we will have the menu blocks inside a wrapper:

```
<div id="region-area">
  <div id="wrapper-region-area">
    <button>...</button>
    <button>...</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

`#wrapper-region-area` will have a fixed height (`35px` in your case) however we will change `#region-area`'s height with JavaScript. And by setting the CSS rule `overflow: hidden` to `#region-area` the trick is done:

- when `#region-area` will have a height of `0` the menu block will be hidden
- when `#region-area` will have the same height as `#wrapper-region-area` the block will be seen

But why all this trouble you may ask?

smooth folding/unfolding animation is the answer! Indeed you can set `transition: all 1s;` to `#region-area` to make the height change linearly. In this case, the block will close in one second. We definately would not have achieved this with `display:none`.

---

### JavaScript

Now let's go through the JavaScript code.

Here's how in a few steps:

1. let's get the position of a menu block, for example the first one `Region`. First, select the element then apply [`.getBoundingClientRect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect):

   ```
   const element = document.querySelector("#wrapper-region-area");
   const dim = element.getBoundingClientRect();
   ```
2. Now add an event listener to `window`, it will trigger the callback function whenever the user scrolls on the page. Inside this callback we will check if the user is above or below the position of the menu block. If the scroll position `currentScrollPos` is lower than the position of the element we will give it its initial height. Otherwise, we will give it a height of `0px`.

So the code looks like so:

```
const element = document.querySelector("#wrapper-region-area");
const dim = element.getBoundingClientRect();

window.onscroll = () => {
const currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
  if (dim.top > currentScrollPos) {
    document.querySelector("#region-area").style.height = `${dim.height}px`;
  } else {
    document.querySelector("#region-area").style.height = '0px';
  }
}
```

---

### Complete code:

click on <kbd>Show code snippet</kbd> > <kbd>Run code snippet</kbd> to preview.

```js
const element = document.querySelector("#wrapper-region-area");
const dim = element.getBoundingClientRect();

window.onscroll = () => {
const currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
  if (dim.top > currentScrollPos) {
    document.querySelector("#region-area").style.height = `${dim.height}px`;
  } else {
    document.querySelector("#region-area").style.height = '0px';
  }
}
```

```css
#region-area {
  transition: all 1s;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.mainmenu-btn {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: avenir;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: solid 2px #f2f2f2;
  width: 100%;
  height: 45px;
  background-color: white;
  transition: all ease 0.5s;
  background-position: right;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: left;
}

.mainmenu-btn:hover {
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.submenu-btn {
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  font-family: avenir;
  width: 100%;
  height: 35px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  border: none;
  border-left: solid 10px;
  transition: all ease 0.5s;
  border-radius: 0px;
  bottom: 5px;
  position: static;
  text-align: left;
}

.vertical-menu {
  border-right: solid 1px #E8E8E8;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #E8E8E8;
  background-color: white;
  height: 100%;
  /*overflow-y: scroll;*/
  /*scroll-behavior: smooth;*/
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-2 text-left vertical-menu" style="padding-right: 1px">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12" style="padding-left: 0px">
      <button class="mainmenu-btn" onclick="showHideSection('region-area', 'region-sign')">Region<i id="region-sign" class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
      <div id="region-area"><div id="wrapper-region-area">
        <button class="submenu-btn prh-btn" onclick="filterRegion('Stockholm', 'region-sign')">Stockholm</button>
        <button class="submenu-btn fh-btn" onclick="filterRegion('Mitt', 'region-sign')">Mitt</button>
        <button class="submenu-btn hh-btn" onclick="filterRegion('Sydväst', 'region-sign')">Sydväst</button>
        <button class="submenu-btn all-btn" onclick="resetData()">Alla</button>
      </div></div>
      <button class="mainmenu-btn" onclick="showHideSection('status-area', 'status-sign')">Status<i id="status-sign" class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
      <div id="status-area">
        <button class="submenu-btn prh-btn" onclick="filterStatus(1)">Programhandling</button>
        <button class="submenu-btn fh-btn" onclick="filterStatus(2)">Förslagshandling</button>
        <button class="submenu-btn hh-btn" onclick="filterStatus(3)">HuvudHandling</button>
        <button class="submenu-btn bh-btn" onclick="filterStatus(4)">Bygghandling</button>
        <button class="submenu-btn all-btn" onclick="resetData()">Alla</button>
      </div>
      <button class="mainmenu-btn" onclick="showHideSection('skede-area', 'skeden-sign')">Skede<i id="skede-sign" class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
      <div id="skede-area">
        <button class="submenu-btn prh-btn" onclick="filterData(1)">Markanvisning</button>
        <button class="submenu-btn fh-btn" onclick="filterData(2)">Affärsutveckling</button>
        <button class="submenu-btn hh-btn" onclick="filterData(3)">Projektutveckling</button>
        <button class="submenu-btn bh-btn" onclick="filterData(4)">Produktion</button>
        <button class="submenu-btn all-btn" onclick="resetData()">Alla</button>
      </div>
      <button class="mainmenu-btn" onclick="showHideSection('tollgates-area', 'tollgates-sign')">Tollgates<i id="tollgates-sign" class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
      <div id="tollgates-area">
        <button class="submenu-btn prh-btn" onclick="filterTollgates('TG0')">TG0</button>
        <button class="submenu-btn fh-btn" onclick="filterTollgates('TG1')">TG1</button>
        <button class="submenu-btn hh-btn" onclick="filterTollgates('TG2')">TG2</button>
        <button class="submenu-btn prh-btn" onclick="filterTollgates('TG3')">TG3</button>
        <button class="submenu-btn fh-btn" onclick="filterTollgates('TG4')">TG4</button>
        <button class="submenu-btn hh-btn" onclick="filterTollgates('TG5')">TG5</button>
        <button class="submenu-btn hh-btn" onclick="filterTollgates('TG6')">TG6</button>
        <button class="submenu-btn all-btn" onclick="resetData()">Alla</button>
      </div>
      <button class="mainmenu-btn" onclick="showHideSection('kalkyl-area', 'kalkyl-sign')">Kalkyl<i id="kalkyl-sign" class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
      <div id="kalkyl-area">
        <button class="submenu-btn prh-btn" onclick="filterKalkyl('Nyckeltalskalkyl')">Nyckeltalskalkyl</button>
        <button class="submenu-btn fh-btn" onclick="filterKalkyl('FH-kalkyl')">FH-kalkyl</button>
        <button class="submenu-btn hh-btn" onclick="filterKalkyl('HH-kalkyl')">HH-kalkyl</button>
        <button class="submenu-btn prh-btn" onclick="filterKalkyl('BH-kalkyl')">BH-kalkyl</button>
        <button class="submenu-btn all-btn" onclick="resetData()">Alla</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> **Note:** in the above code the effect will only work for the first menu block. You can implement the feature for the other blocks using the exact same technique.